# Angular Reactive Forms binding a control to multiple inputs doesn't refresh the others

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms

When I am using reactive forms and try to access the same control in multiple Inputs it looks like it's only a one-way-data-binding (input-to-model).
If I edit an input it will update the model correctly but it will not refresh the other input as well.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="test" id="in1">
<input type="text" formControlName="test" id="in2">
```

My work-a-round is to add the following line to both inputs:

```
(change)="form.controls.test.setValue(form.controls.test.value)
```

But to be honest this looks like a pretty bad solution. Am I doing anything wrong here? What is the correct way to archive this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/yALzCIHgOA463OvGi5rP

Comment: Why would you want two inputs synced to the same control? I do not understand your use case or see a practical application for it.

Comment: At any rate, I would recommend reading the docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName. I believe you will be able to answer your own question after that.

Comment: The correct way to achieve it is: not to do it. What is the aim of have two inputs in the same form? If you want, you can make two forms (the [formGroup] can be referred to the same variable)

Comment: I want to set a daterange with several different inputs. I want to allow the user to select a whole month from a select or only choose one day with a datepicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't sure why you need exactly 2 fields with same `formControlName` but a solution could be - Create custom angular element.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-element',
  templateUrl: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./custom-element.component.css']
})
export class CustomElementComponent implements ControlValueAccessor

@Input() value: any 

writeValue(value: any) {
  // Some if statements
  this.value = value;
}

registerOnChange(fn: Function) {
  // your code here
}
registerOnTouched(fn: Function) {
  // your code here
}
```

And in the parent component template

```
<custom-element formControlName="fieldname"></custom-element>
```

For more details (and deeper explanation), you can check https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: I want to manipulate a date with separate selects for month, date, year etc. But my plan was to use the same value in the background. I think it's not possible without a custom element like you suggested (or my hack).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngModel`:

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
        <h2>Test = {{form?.controls.test.value}}</h2>
        1. <input type="text" formControlName="test" [(ngModel)]="test"> 
    2. <input type="text" formControlName="test" [(ngModel)]="test"> 
    3.
        <button type="button" (click)="form.controls.test.setValue('manual')">change with setValue</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a
>   property binding and an event binding

For example:

```
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
```

Is equal to:

```
<app-sizer [size]="fontSizePx" (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event"></app-sizer>
```

[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxycra)

Comment: NOT is good mixing Reactive and Template Forms (formControlName and ngModel)

Comment: It feels a bit dirty. Especially because I have to create a new model field "test" which is redundant with the form values. This is basically the same as I did with my change-event.